# (ERROR 9!!!) Coping a value from a cells to another in different worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I try to copy different values from cells in the first workbooks (let's name it template.xlsx) to another (item.xls)

I tried this but it doesn't work (ERROR 9)

`Woorbooks("item.xls").Worksheets("Unit_Of_Measure").Cells(i, 2) = Workbooks("template.xlsx").Worksheets("Introduction").Cells(i, 8).Value`

Any suggestion ?

Comment: `Woorbooks`??? O_O

Comment: Error 9 is a "Subscript out of range" error.  I notice one of your workbooks is `.xls` and the other is `.xlsx`which means if your `i` value is larger than 65536, you'll end up with that error.

Comment: Hi, can oyu give the whole code? Just guessing - it can be that you have declatred i as integer, and not as long.

Comment: @Vityata I changed the variable i into "long" but still don't work, i'll post as a comment the whole code, please check if there is any error !! thank youu

Comment: @tigeravatar  I changed the variable i into "long" but still don't work, i'll post as a comment the whole code, please check if there is any error !! thank youu

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest a different way, may look complicated but it's easy and more clean.This code will do what you need but both workbooks should be at the same folder or path, and it's important to have "i" var controlled dependign on what you need. Let's say we're going to make the copy by a button click located at template.xls :

```
Private Sub button1_click()
   Var_data = Introduction.Cells(i,8)
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\item.xls"
   ThisWorkbook.Activate
   Unit_Of_Measure.Cells(i,2) = var_data
   Workbooks("item.xls").Close SaveChanges:=True
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

First you capture data on a var, then you open your admin book, put the data on the cell you want and close that workbook saving changes (you decide if you keep this line or mantain the workbook open and save manually). Also, Application.screenupdating it's a line that helps your screen doesn't flick when changing between workbooks.

Hope it helps friend !

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim classeur As Workbook
Dim derlig As Integer 'dernière ligne de la colonne B de template
derlig = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set classeur = Application.Workbooks.Add
With classeur
Sheets.Add
Sheets.Add
Sheets.Add
Worksheets(1).Name = "Items"
Worksheets(2).Name = "Unit_Of_Measure"
Worksheets(3).Name = "Item_Tax_Authorities"
Worksheets(4).Name = "Item_Optional_Fields"
.SaveAs "C:\Users\Ikrame\Desktop\Stage SVL\mass upload\Item upload.xls"
End With
Cells(1, 1).Value = "ITEMNO"
Cells(1, 2).Value = "DESC"
Cells(1, 3).Value = "ITEMBRIKID"
Cells(1, 4).Value = "FMTITEMNO"
Cells(1, 5).Value = "CATEGORY"
Cells(1, 6).Value = "CNTLACCT"
Cells(1, 7).Value = "STOCKITEM"
Cells(1, 8).Value = "STOCKUNIT"
Cells(1, 9).Value = "UNITWGT"
Cells(1, 10).Value = "SELLABLE"
Cells(1, 11).Value = "WEIGHTUNIT"
Dim i As Long
For i = 5 To derlig
'Ne pas oublier la partie de l'ITEM NUMBER
Cells(i - 3, 3).Value = "PRODCT"
Cells(i - 3, 10).Value = "1,05"
Cells(i - 3, 11).Value = "Kg"
Cells(i - 3, 7).Value = "TRUE"
Workbooks("Item upload.xls").Worksheets("Items").Cells(i - 3, 2) = Workbooks("template.xlsx").Worksheets("Introduction").Cells(i, 3).Value
Workbooks("Item upload.xls").Worksheets("Items").Cells(i - 3, 4) = Workbooks("template.xlsx").Worksheets("Introduction").Cells(i, 2).Value
```